# Rspec command line argument not supported?

Tags: ruby, rspec, command-line-arguments, watir, watir-webdriver

My website will be tested in different languages and browser (Firefox, Chrome).
I use `Ruby`, `watir-webdriver` and `rspec`.
How do I write tests with `Ruby`, `watir` and `rspec` , that I can specify command line arguments ?

Example: `rspec testfile.rb 1 2`

- 1 => language finnland (load XML file)
- 2 => firefox

`rspec` gives me an error message for this example code:

```
argOne = ARGV[0].to_i
argTwo = ARGV[1].to_i
```

`rspec` can't process the command line argument?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It would be useful if you posted the error message

Comment: formatting code and text, the `rspec` and command line argument should are sufficient to make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post on the ruby forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1537620), you cannot pass argument to `rspec`, but you can pass variable from the command line via the `environment variables`

- command line ( on Linux / bash )

```sh
LANG=1 BROWSER=2 rspec testFile.rb
```

- command line ( on Windows )

```
set LANG=1
set BROWSER=2
rspec testFile.rb
```

- in your `testFile.rb`

```rb
 argOne = ENV["LANG"].to_i
 argTwo = ENV["BROWSER"].to_i
```

Comment: Under windows it does not work. I get the message: `This command is not known`

Comment: under windows, command to set the environment are different. Use `set var=value` to set environment variable first then run the rspec command.

Comment: No result for this call = `set LANG=1 rspec testFile.rb`. If use `set LANG=1` and after that I use `rspec testFile.rb`. I got the following error message: `uninitialized constant LANG (NameError)`. LANG ist definded as `argOne = ENV["LANG"].to_i` into the Ruby File

Comment: Can you check if the environment variable are properly set ( using `set` ) ?

Comment: `set Lang=1` => `set Lang` Output: `LANG=1` AND `set LANG=1 rspec testFile.rb` => `set LANG` Output: `LANG=1 rspec testFile.rb`.

Comment: Could you try the way described in the updated answer, I unfortunately don't run windows at the time

Comment: When I using `set LANG` on the CMD the environment variable Output is `LANG=1`

Comment: You run each line separately on windows first `set LANG=1` then `BROWSER=2` then `rspec testFile.rb`

Comment: Yes. I run each line separately on windows

Comment: I tested it with ruby (I have not installed rspec on my windows machine) and `print ENV["BROWSER"].to_i` and `print ENV["LANG"].to_i` worked correctly in irb